# Removing white space between main content and a sticky footer

Tags: html, css

I'm using a sticky footer and it keeps being pushed down past the browser height, causing a large amount of whitespace to appear between my main content and the footer. When I use Firefox's inspect element tool however it appears exactly how I want it, removing the white space.

I also have a jQuery slider I'm using called nivoslider but I don't think that's having any affect on it.

Any suggestions?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title>Page Title</title>

    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link href="css/nivo-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">

    <script src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('#slider').nivoSlider({
                effect: 'fade', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
                animSpeed: 400, // Slide transition speed
                pauseTime: 5000, // How long each slide will show
                startSlide: 0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
                directionNav: true, // Next & Prev navigation
                controlNav: false, // 1,2,3... navigation
                controlNavThumbs: false, // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
                pauseOnHover: false, // Stop animation while hovering
                manualAdvance: false, // Force manual transitions
                prevText: 'Last', // Prev directionNav text
                nextText: 'Next', // Next directionNav text
            });
        });

    </script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="header">

        <div class ="title">
            <a href="#"><img src="res/title.png" id="title-img" alt=" "></a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar_inner">
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li> 
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="content">


            <div id="column-left" class="column">
                <p>text text text text text text TEXT</p>
            </div>

            <div class="C-wrapper">

                <div id="column-right" class="column">
                     <p>text text text text text text TEXT</p>
                </div>

                <div class="slider-wrapper">

                    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                        <a href="#"><img src="res/slider/slider-img1.jpg" alt="LAN" title="#caption1" data-transition="" /></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="res/slider/slider-img2.jpg" alt="LOL" title="#caption2" data-transition="" /></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="res/slider/slider-img3.jpg" alt="Starcraft" title="#caption3" data-transition="" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="caption1" class="nivo-html-caption">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <p>text text text text</p>
                </div>

                <div id="caption2" class="nivo-html-caption">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <p>text text text text text</p>
                </div>

                <div id="caption3" class="nivo-html-caption">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <p>text text text text text</p>
                </div>

                <div id="column-center">
                    <p>text text text text text text TEXT</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>
 </body>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
text-decoration:none;   
}

html{
height: 100%;
}

body{
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
background:#1010bf url(../res/bg/bg-hex.png);   
}

#header{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%
margin-top: 10px;   
}

.title{
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
position: relative;
width: 50%;
}

.navbar{
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 35px;
padding-top: 10px;
position: relative;
min-height: 30px;
width: 100%;
background: #525454;
float: left;
border-top-color: #000;
border-top-width: 5px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-bottom-color: #000;
border-bottom-width: 5px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
}

.navbar_inner{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 50%;
}

.navbar .navbar_inner ul li{
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 10px 40px;
display: inline;    
}

.navbar a:link{
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #059695;
}

.navbar a:visited{
color: #059695;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar a:active{
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar a:hover{
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
color: #00f7ff;
}

.navbar a:focus{
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 40px 40px;
color: #00f7ff;
}


#wrapper{
margin: 0 auto -75px auto;
width:1100px;
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
}

#content{
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
clear: both;
}

.column{
background-color: #fff;
width: 250px;
height: 500px;
}

#column-left{
float: left;
}

#column-right{
float: right;
}

#column-center{
margin: 10px 30px;
float: left;
width: 540px;
height: 240px;
background-color: #fff; 
}

.C-wrapper{
clear: right;
position: relative;
}

.slider-wrapper{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 540px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #000;
border-width: 5px;
}

.footer{
background-color: #525454;
border-top-color: #000;
border-top-width: 5px;
border-top-style: solid;    
}

.footer, .push{
clear: both;
height: 70px;
}
```

Comment: where's the CSS for the `.push` div?

Comment: it was suppose to be with the last .footer class. I fixed it, i was messing with it to try and fix my problem

Comment: set footer to be `height: 70px;`

Comment: The footer is being set to 70px at the very bottom of the CSS file.

Comment: can you replicate the problem in a fiddle?

Comment: I tried but was not able to replicate it. In the fiddle the footer acted exactly how I want it. I will keep trying however and let you know

Comment: I was able to get the footer to act how I want by changing the min height of the wrapper from min-height:100% to min-height: 93.1%; but I feel like this isn't aa fix that will work well in the long run. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The #wrapper div is currently set to be a minimum height of 100%; try removing that declaration, as it is likely causing the main content to be a minimum size of the entire browser window, which will naturally push all other content below the window.

Comment: That pushes the footer up but it makes it not be a sticky footer anymore i.e. the footer wont stay at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend removing the `min-height: 100%;` and instead adding `background-color: #525454;` to the html in css.

Looks like this:

```
html  {
background-color: #525454;
}
```

This will fill anything under the footer with that color making it fill to the end of the browser.

[My portfolio reference](http://jpowell43.mydevryportfolio.com/CleanPortfolio/index.html)

I also found this link if you want your footer to be a set height and stay at the bottom.

[Set height footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/)

Comment: I do plan on putting information in the footer and with this fix I don't see how I could since I would not have a footer div that would align with the visible footer. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: You are missing something but don't worry! You will still have a footer div to hold any information that may go in there or you can use an html5 tag called footer. :p What this effect does is as soon as the footer or last structure like element on the page ends it will stack on top of the HTML making it look like one element. If the footer is only a color element you don't need to worry but if your using a repeatable pattern you need to make sure the footer height is the size of the image or it repeats odd with the html's image.